# I want to change image dimensions to specific dimensions in php

Tags: php, image

I need to change image dimentions to related dimensions which i provide.

i do a code but that code is not working, i i provide some dimensions, that type of images only suppoerted.  so i want to do that if any user provide image.

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $uploadedFileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $temporaryFilePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $grouped = uniqid();

    // Replace 'upload_folder' with the actual path to your upload directory
    $uploadDirectory = 'assets/images/';

    $destinationPath = $uploadDirectory . $uploadedFileName;

    // Check if the uploaded file is an image
    $imageInfo = getimagesize($temporaryFilePath);
    if ($imageInfo === false) {
        echo "Not a valid image file.";
    } else {
        $uploadedWidth = $imageInfo[0];
        $uploadedHeight = $imageInfo[1];

        $allowedDimensions = array(
            array(1024, 1024),
            array(1152, 896),
            array(1216, 832),
            array(1344, 768),
            array(1536, 640),
            array(640, 1536),
            array(768, 1344),
            array(832, 1216),
            array(896, 1152)
        );

        $isAllowed = false;
        foreach ($allowedDimensions as $dimensions) {
            if ($uploadedWidth === $dimensions[0] && $uploadedHeight === $dimensions[1]) {
                $isAllowed = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$isAllowed) {
            // Determine the image type and create an image resource
            $imageType = $imageInfo[2]; // This will be IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, etc.

            switch ($imageType) {
                case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                    $sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($temporaryFilePath);
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                    $sourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($temporaryFilePath);
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                    $sourceImage = imagecreatefromgif($temporaryFilePath);
                    break;
                // Add other cases for different image types here if needed
                default:
                    echo "Unsupported image type.";
                    break;
            }

            $closestDimensions = $allowedDimensions[0];
            $minDistance = PHP_INT_MAX;

            foreach ($allowedDimensions as $dimensions) {
                $distance = abs($uploadedWidth - $dimensions[0]) + abs($uploadedHeight - $dimensions[1]);
                if ($distance < $minDistance) {
                    $minDistance = $distance;
                    $closestDimensions = $dimensions;
                }
            }

            // Resize the image to the closest allowed dimensions
            $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($closestDimensions[0], $closestDimensions[1]);
            imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $closestDimensions[0], $closestDimensions[1], $uploadedWidth, $uploadedHeight);

            $resizedImagePath = $uploadDirectory . 'resized_' . $uploadedFileName;

            if (imagepng($resizedImage, $resizedImagePath)) {
                $destinationPath = $resizedImagePath;
                imagedestroy($resizedImage);
                imagedestroy($sourceImage);
            } else {
                echo "Failed to resize and save the image.";
            }
        }
        // Move the uploaded file to the destination directory
        if (move_uploaded_file($temporaryFilePath, $destinationPath)) {      
        }
    }
```

I want to crop image relavent dimentions which i provide.
this code is provide me new image but that image is not croped as i want.

Comment: So you are going to have to tell us how you want the image cropped, we cannot guess that from the code